# NGINX - Host 2 HTTPS Node apps

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, debian, reverse-proxy

I'm new to Nginx, and I have some trouble with hosting 2 websites on my RaspberryPi (Raspbian).

I have 2 domains, site1.com (:8080) and site2.com(:8000), both are Node.JS apps (with Express). I have working SSL certifications with Let's Encrypt for both.

This is my site1 nginx config (/etc/nginx/site-available/site1):

```
server {
    server_name site2.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.11:8080;
    }
}
```

This is my site2 nginx config (/etc/nginx/site-available/site2):

```
server {
    server_name site1.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.11:8000;
    }
}
```

So indeed there is no part of 443 in these conf files but https://site2.com is working well but https://site1.com redirect me to the webpage of https://site2.com (keeping the site1 URL). I guess it's because my_server_ip:443 is already taken by site2 (no ??).

And the http://site2.com give me a 502 Bad Gateway and is not redirected to https (site1 is well redirected to his https).

This is the server part of my Node apps, they are the same for the 2 apps (except a port and SSL URI)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/site1or2.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/site1or2.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/site1or2.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const urlencodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //redirect to https
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(8080); //8000 for my site2.com

httpsServer.listen('443', () => {
    console.log('Server https listening on Port 443');
})
```

I tried to change the Nginx confs to add 'listen 443; SSL on;...' but I have always errors like 'Failed to start A high-performance web server and a reverse proxy server' and I don't understand how to fix it.
So is the problem from my JS code or my Nginx confs? (or both maybe..?)

Thank for reading, it's my first StackOverflow post, I hope I didn't forget information and sorry if there is an English mistake.

Have a good evening (or day)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly understood how does multiples node websites hosting with SSL works, in the node.JS configuration (app.js) the app has to only listen to 1 port (8080 and 8000 for me) and must not refer to SSL and port 443 at all.
All the ssl configurations and https redirections have to be in the Nginx conf, for exemple, my file /etc/nginx/sites-available/site1:

```
server {
    server_name site1.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/privkey.pem;
        server_name site1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.11:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And the same for site2 with port 8000.